# When I decrypt with AES in ASP.Net Core I lose some data

Tags: asp.net, aes, asp.net-core-3.1

**My two functions:**

```
public static void encrypt(IFormFile uploadFile)
{
    ICryptoTransform transform = _crypt_provider.CreateEncryptor();

    //Extraer los datos del csv en un string
    string text;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(uploadFile.OpenReadStream()))//, Encoding.UTF8
    {
        // lectura del contenido del archivo
        text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    byte[] encrypted_bytes = transform.TransformFinalBlock(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text) , 0, text.Length);

    string textoEncrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted_bytes);
    //string textoEncrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted_bytes);

    Debug.WriteLine($"El texto ingresado = {text} \nEl texto encriptado = {textoEncrypted}");
    File.WriteAllText(uploadFile.FileName, textoEncrypted);
}

public static string decrypt(IFormFile uploadFile)
{
    string text;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(uploadFile.OpenReadStream()))//, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")
    {
        // lectura del contenido del archivo
        text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    ICryptoTransform transform = _crypt_provider.CreateDecryptor();

    byte[] encrypted_bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
    //byte[] encrypted_bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    byte[] dencrypted_bytes = transform.TransformFinalBlock(encrypted_bytes, 0, encrypted_bytes.Length);
    string textoDesencriptado = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dencrypted_bytes);
    //File.WriteAllText(uploadFile.FileName, textoDesencriptado);
    Debug.WriteLine($"El texto ingresado = {text} \nEl texto desencriptado = {textoDesencriptado}");
    return textoDesencriptado;
}
```

**This is my .csv input:**

```
50001,José,,Peréz,Gonzáles,1998-07-06
50002,Miguel,,Hermandez,Hermandez,1998-07-06
50003,Raúl,,Ramirez,Gutierrez,1998-07-06
50004,Laura2,Araceli,Ordoñez,Alcazar,1998-07-06
50005,Yazmin2,,Herrera,García,1998-07-06
50007,Prb2, Prb,Prb3,Herreras,1998-07-06
```

**And the output:**

```
50001,José,,Peréz,Gonzáles,1998-07-06
50002,Miguel,,Hermandez,Hermandez,1998-07-06
50003,Raúl,,Ramirez,Gutierrez,1998-07-06
50004,Laura2,Araceli,Ordoñez,Alcazar,1998-07-06
50005,Yazmin2,,Herrera,García,1998-07-06
50007,Prb2, Prb,Prb3,Herreras,1998
```

**Missing -07-06 in the 50007.**

I'm using UTF-8 because I need to encrypt special characters.

Answer (score 0):

General speaking if the decrypt fails you read nothing.
So the error must be on the reading / encrypting.
Change this lines on the text to encrypt - not give the text.Length, but the array length.

```
byte[] toEncryptArray = ASCIIEncoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(toEncrypt);


byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
```